# How can i get a SessionScope Object in my Bean

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, session-scope

i search a way how i can access a class in the sessionscope.

I have this class:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagerBean implements Serializable{...}
```

and i will access some fields from a other bean. How can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by taking the bean as a `@ManagedProperty` of the other bean and then just access it as an usual property in the action methods.

```
@ManagedBean
public class OtherBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userManagerBean}")
    private UserManagerBean userManagerBean;

    // ...
}
```

It will be set directly *after* construction, so it wouldn't be available in the constructor. If you'd like to do some init stuff which relies on its availablility, then make use of `@PostConstruct`:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        userManagerBean.doStuff();
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this work perfect. For all other People: You need a setter and getter for the userManagerBean in this example.

Comment: That's just obvious :) It's after all a **javabean**.